# Why can't i return a specific propery from state in store, while it works fine when returning its parent object?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

that might seem to be a little confusing but basically i just want to access a propety from the state itself using useSelector hook at any component to retrieve a specific property as follows, what i mean by that, for example, i configured my slice which has an initial state with the following structure, however it should just do fine since i use useSelector hook to get those state values from there, but it only works when i try to access only its parent object but its properties...

in my component, i have to be able to access state.filters.departureTimeRange property which im pretty sure it has already data and already tested when i printed out the `state.filters` itself.
But i dont get whats wrong with the properties of that state object and just returns `undefined` when i try to print the properties inside...

to sum up: state.filters is OK
but state.filters.departureTimeRange or any other property just makes me cancer, been messing around this for maybe hours but no luck! any help is so appreciated, thanks a lot in advance

**My Component**

```
const DepartureHour = () => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('evening');
  const [departureTime, setDepartureTime] = useState<[number, number]>([0, 24]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const departureTimeRange = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.filters.departureTimeRange);
 

  useEffect(() => {
    if (departureTimeRange) {
      console.log(departureTimeRange);
    }
  }, [departureTimeRange]);
```

**filtersSlice**

```
interface FiltersState {

    priceRange: [number, number];
    departureTimeRange: [number, number];
    seatLayout: string;
    busCompanies: string[];
    services: string[];
    destination: string[];
    departure: string[];
  }
  
  export interface RootState {
    filters: FiltersState;
  }

  const initialState: RootState = {
    filters: {
      priceRange: [0, 1000],
      departureTimeRange: [0, 24],
      seatLayout: '',
      busCompanies: [],
      services: [],
      destination: [],
      departure: [],
    },
  };


const filtersSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'filters',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
          setDepartureTimeRange(state, action:PayloadAction<FiltersState['departureTimeRange'] >) {
            state.filters.departureTimeRange = action.payload
        },
          //other reducers
})

export const {setDepartureTimeRange} = filtersSlice.actions;

export default filtersSlice.reducer;
```

**rootReducer**

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    seats: seatsReducer,
    selectedSeats: selectedSeatsReducer,
    filters: filtersReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you have double folding:

You define reducer as:

```
filters: filtersReducer
```

Then you define initialState:

```
const initialState: RootState = {
    filters: {…}
```

This basically would give you `store.filters.filters`

You also have incorrect cast to RootState, the root state is a type of `store` it’s not a type of slice `state`

So

```
const departureTimeRange = useSelector((store: RootState) => store.filters.filters.departureTimeRange);
```

Should work as expected

P.s.: you should remove `:RootState` from initialState, then you should remove key `filters` from initialState and it should work as expected (with your current useSelector)

Comment: how come i didnt realize that ! i cant tell you how you just saved my life, that was real pain for the last few days to me, and now works like a charm, thanks again !!

Comment: cheeeeeeeers :)